# can't get alert to work after AsyncTask

Tags: android, facebook, android-asynctask

i'm using facebook runner to apply some facebook api tesk.
i want to check if i got a JSON object with data or and error message so i'm checking the "message" field to check if it's null.
if it is not null and i have a massage, i want to display the message and exit the application.

this is my code in my activity:

```
public class Loader extends Activity implements FacebookConnectionListener, ServerDataListener {
    private TextView loaderStatus;
    private Facebook facebook;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner facebookRunner;
    private FacebookConnection facebookConnection;   

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loader);
        facebook = new Facebook(facebookAppId);
        facebookRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        facebookConnection = new FacebookConnection(this, 1);
        facebookRunner.request("me",facebookConnection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookResponse(final String response , int step) {
        final JSONObject facebookResults = convertToJSON(response);
        final Context thisContext = (Context) getBaseContext();
        String id = "", name = "", gender = "", homeTown = "";
        Drawable profilePicture = null;

        if (step == 1) {
            if (facebookResults.isNull("message")) {
                try {
                    id = facebookResults.getString("id");
                    name = facebookResults.getString("name");
                    gender = facebookResults.getString("gender");
                    JSONObject homeTownObject = (JSONObject) facebookResults.get("hometown");
                    homeTown = homeTownObject.getString("name");
                    profilePicture = getProfilePicture(id);

                } catch (JSONException e) { 
                    alert("Facebook", e.toString(), "Ok", thisContext);
                }
                facebookCurrentUser = new FacebookCurrentUser(id, name, gender);
                facebookCurrentUser.setHomeTown(homeTown);
                facebookCurrentUser.setProfilePicture(profilePicture);
                app.setFacebookCurrentUser(facebookCurrentUser);
                facebookConnection = new FacebookConnection(this, 2);   
                this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        loaderStatus.setText("Getting friends details");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        alert("Facebook", "Can't get user details! Please try again", "Ok", thisContext);
                    }
                }); 
            }           
        }

public void alert (String title, String message, String ok, Context listener)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(listener);
    alert.setMessage(message);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setPositiveButton(ok, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();   
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

this is FacebookConnection class:

```
public class FacebookConnection implements RequestListener {
    private FacebookConnectionListener listener;
    private int step;

    public FacebookConnection (FacebookConnectionListener listener, int step) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.step = step;
    }

    public void updateFacebookListener(String response) {
        listener.onFacebookResponse(response, step);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        updateFacebookListener(response);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) { }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) { }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) { }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) { }
 }
```

the FacebookConnectionListener interface:

```
public interface FacebookConnectionListener {
    public void onFacebookResponse(String response, int step);
}
```

my alerts keep giving me the :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

and i can't understand why.. help ?

Comment: This code is part of what? Is this class an *Activity*? Also, where's the *AsyncFacebookRunner*?

Comment: you're right.. i've edited to post

Comment: Ok, but how is this method being executed? When, by what thread? I still don't see where you are using the *AsyncFacebookRunner*

Comment: this is the listener for the facebook asyncrunner. when the asynctask is over it sends the response to this function

Comment: I don't understand, I thought you said it's the *Activity*, now it's the listener? Please, edit your question and add all of the relevant code, otherwise we're just speculating here and it can take forever.

Comment: done. hope its more clear now.. thanks!

Comment: Ok, now what is this *alert* method? where is it defined? Also, that error message, on what exact line is it thrown?

Comment: it just run a simple alertdialog which on it constractur it take the context as parameter

Comment: This I think has to do with how/when you try to display the alert. Does the *loaderStatus.setText* also throw that exception? Where is the exception thrown exactly? Take a lot here: http://www.stevenmarkford.com/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-in-android/

Comment: ok i've added the alert code... the loaderStatus.setText works but when i'm replacing it with the same alert, i get the same exeption.. weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, try this:

```
public void alert (String title, String message, String ok) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Loader.this).create();
            alert.setMessage(message);
            alert.setTitle(title);
            alert.setPositiveButton(ok, new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Instead of what you have now, and when you call it, just call it like any other method:

```
this.alert("Facebook", "Can't get user details! Please try again", "Ok")
```

I'm not exactly sure where it goes wrong, it even might have to do with you forgetting the *create()* part when constructing the dialog.

Hope this will sort things for you.

Comment: it says: The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new Runnable(){}) is undefined

Comment: i'm sorry man, i can't understand it. the code you wrote provide the error i've written above, and i just don't get it why the loaderStatus.setText works and the alert doesn't...

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be *Loader.this* and not *this*. Also, notice that I changed the *AlertDialog.Builder alert* to *AlertDialog alert* in my answer. As for the why the *setText* does not fail, I'm not 100% sure, so let's first see if what I wrote works or not.

Comment: thanks @Nitzan Tomer ! i didn't time to check it yet (a verrry long day) but will do soon and update the results.. many thanks!

Comment: Sure, no probs. But I gotta say that from this thread and the previous one in which I helped you, it kinda seems like you're a bit over your head here. Maybe before you jump to android development you should first strengthen your java basis? yom tov.

Comment: you're probably right :) but that how i love to study, i'm inventing a project to myself, and then i'm studying throw it..
actually if to be more specific, usually i'm having problems with services and thread :) i think i'm not completely getting the mechanism if it.. but i sure do work on it :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is appearing is because you are trying to update Ui from a different thread. As this is a partial code, I can suggest you changing your code to

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    loaderStatus.setText("Getting friends details");
                }
            });
```

where MyActivity is your Activity's name.

Comment: He is using *runOnUiThread* as it clearly states in his code.

Answer (score 0):

the easy way:

u can publishProgress(something)

and process the publishing, to show your alert :D